# Unable to checkout apache cxf example

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, cxf

I was going trough some samples from apache CXF project http://cxf.apache.org/docs/sample-projects.html

Wanted to checkout couple of things to see how they work i.e

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/cxf/trunk/distribution/src/main/release/samples/ws_security/

However I cannot checkout I get this error :

[image]

Did anyone expirience the same/similar issues before?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "viewvc" URL is for browsing only, not for a checkout.  Use:

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/cxf/trunk/distribution/src/main/release/samples/

Comment: Hi,When I tried importing with this url -  http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/cxf/trunk/distribution/src/main/release/samples I get this error message "Access to '/repos/asf/!svn/me' forbidden" Has anyone faced a similar issue? 
- Karthick

Comment: Git users can get the samples from this Git repo - https://github.com/apache/cxf/tree/trunk/distribution/src/main/release/samples

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier to get it from Git [repository](https://github.com/apache/cxf/tree/master/distribution/src/main/release/samples).